# What is the difference between mixed-effects modelling in the RStan and lme4 packages?

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I've recently begun running some multilevel/hierarchical models. Initially I was using [rstan](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstan/index.html)/[rstanarm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstanarm/index.html), but then switched to the [lme4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) package.

Is the difference between these two packages only in the use of Bayesian priors (as in `rstan`) or not, as in `lme4`?

Comment: Stan is used to perform a Bayesian analysis, lme4 is used to perform a frequentist analysis.

Comment: This question is a little too broad and/or opinion-based as written.  `lme4` and `rstanarm` are fitting essentially the same models, in different statistical frameworks (as @Glen says). Unless you have a more specific question in mind, this boils down to "are [frequentist methods] effective for [statistical analysis], or should [Bayesian methods] be used instead?", which is not an easily answerable question.

Comment: Glen's comment appears correct since looking more at the functions in each package, I'm just going to narrow down the question in case anyone else has it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`lme4` is fully frequentist (technically, it is ["empirical Bayesian"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_Bayes_method)), while `rstanarm` is fully Bayesian. That means there are more differences than just whether a prior is used. For example:

- `rstanarm` reports marginal medians of the posterior density for each parameter, while `lme4` reports maximum likelihood estimates (*approximately* analogous to the maximum *a posteriori* (MAP) estimator, or mode of the posterior distribution, given uninformative priors - but see [this CV answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313617/is-the-invariance-property-of-the-ml-estimator-nonsensical-from-a-bayesian-persp/337240?stw=2#337240) for discussion of why this is a loose analogy)
- `rstanarm` reports posterior intervals based on quantiles of the marginal posterior distribution (*not* the more classical highest posterior density intervals), `lme4` reports Wald standard errors or likelihood profile confidence intervals
- diagnostics and convergence checking procedures are radically different.

For what it's worth,

- `brms`, also based on Stan, implements a broad class of GLMMs (somewhat broader than `rstanarm`, I think)
- `MCMCglmm` implements a broad class of Bayesian mixed models (based on older MCMC approaches rather than Hamiltonian MC)
- the `blme` package implements a partly Bayesian approach to mixed models that allows for weakly or strongly informative priors, but reports MAP estimates (it builds on `lme4`'s technology)
- the `R-INLA` package (not on CRAN) uses integrated nested Laplace approximations; it also allows priors and returns MAP estimates