# Invariance property

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, estimators, sufficient-statistics, consistency

I am a bit confused regarding what exactly is the invariance property of sufficient estimators, consistent estimators and maximum likelihood estimators. 
As far as I know,

1. *Invariance property of consistent estimators is* : If $T$ is a consistent estimator of $\theta$, and $f$ is a continuous function then $f(T)$ is a consistent estimator of $f(\theta)$.
2. *Invariance property of sufficient estimators is* : If $T$ is sufficient estimator of $\theta$ and $f$ is one-one, onto function then $f(T)$ is sufficient estimator of $f(\theta)$, also $f(T)$ is sufficient estimator of $\theta$, and $T$ is sufficient estimator of $f(\theta)$.
3. *Invariance property of maximum likelihood estimators(MLE) is* : If $T$ is a MLE of $\theta$, and $f$ is a continuous/ one-one, onto function then $f(T)$ is a MLE of $f(\theta)$.

Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere and please tell me the least I need to check for it as I am appearing for a competitive exam where time really matters.

Answer (score 4):

These are somewhat different properties , and throwing them together under the same name mostly is confusing. But:

1. This is correct, but I have never before seen this named invariance.
2. Confused. We talk about sufficient *statistics* not estimators. Of course an estimator is a statistic, but $T$ being sufficient statistic (in a model parametrized by $\theta$, or *for $\theta$*) says in itself not that  $T$ is a good estimator!  If $T$ is sufficient, and also a good estimator for $\theta$, then still $1000000 T$ is sufficient, but maybe not a good estimator (for $\theta$.)  Of your requirements for $f$ then one-to-one is essential, onto is unnecessary. Then we can reformulate: If $T$ is sufficient for $\theta$ and $f$ is one-one, then $f(T)$ is also sufficient for $\theta$.
3. Mostly right, but you don't need all those conditions on $f$. See [Invariance property of maximum likelihood estimator?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80584/invariance-property-of-maximum-likelihood-estimator).

Comment: But for the sufficient Statistic, it holds both ways right? i.e, If T is sufficient statistic of theta and f is a one-one function then f(T) is a sufficient statistic of theta, and also f(T) is sufficient statistic of f(theta) , and T is also a sufficient statistic of f(theta).

Comment: Yes, its right.