# Maximum likelihood estimate of positive semidefinite matrix equivalent to MLE of its inverse

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, covariance-matrix

While reading on Gaussian Discriminant Analysis, I came across a derivation of the parameters (specifically, $\sum$) using Maximum Likelihood Estimation that claimed that the MLE of $\sum$ is equivalent to the MLE of $\sum^{-1}$,
$\sum$ being the covariance matrix of the multivariate Gaussian distribution.

Though I am able to reach the same result without using the above, I want to know:

1. Why does this hold true?
2. Does this hold true for any positive definite matrix $A \in \mathbb S_{++}^{n}$, or does the fact that $\sum$ is a covariance matrix play a role in proving this.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80584/invariance-property-of-maximum-likelihood-estimator

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen that helps to answer my questions. Would you like to formulate that into a point-wise answer for anyone else that may run into this?